# Error when trying to run scapy shell

Tags: python, scapy

I just installed scapy as told on the documentation (on Windows 7). However, when I try to run the command 'scapy' from cmd it gives me an error:

```
C:\Users\THOMAS>scapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\Scripts\\scapy", line 23, in <module>
    from scapy.main import interact
ImportError: No module named 'scapy'
```

And the modules also doesn't seem to work, it gives me these errors:

```
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
WARNING: can't import layer inet: 'module' object has no attribute 'IPPROTO_IPIP'
WARNING: can't import layer dhcp: 'module' object has no attribute 'IPPROTO_IPIP'
WARNING: can't import layer dns: 'module' object has no attribute 'IPPROTO_IPIP'
WARNING: can't import layer gprs: 'module' object has no attribute 'IPPROTO_IPIP'
WARNING: can't import layer hsrp: 'module' object has no attribute 'IPPROTO_IPIP'
WARNING: can't import layer inet6: 'module' object has no attribute 'IPPROTO_IPIP'
WARNING: can't import layer dhcp6: 'module' object has no attribute 'IPPROTO_IPIP'
WARNING: can't import layer sctp: 'module' object has no attribute 'IPPROTO_IPIP'
WARNING: can't import layer ipsec: 'module' object has no attribute 'IPPROTO_IPIP'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python26/scapy test", line 2, in <module>
    scapy.send(scapy.IP()/scapy.ICMP())
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 251, in send
    __gen_send(conf.L3socket(*args, **kargs), x, inter=inter, loop=loop, count=count,verbose=verbose, realtime=realtime)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 237, in __gen_send
    os.write(1,".")
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

When I try to run this simple command:

```
scapy.send(scapy.IP()/scapy.ICMP())
```

*Please i'm already been trying to installing it for over a week now, and any way I try*: **I can't get it to work.**

Comment: If you have access to a virtualization software (like VirtualBox + vagrant would be a good combo) - I highly suggest running it in a Linux machine.

Answer (score 2):

You have to open file: "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scapy\layers\inet6.py" 
edit last string: bind_layers(IPv6, IP, nh = socket.IPPROTO_IPIP )
replace with: bind_layers(IPv6, IP, nh = 4 )
and delete file "inet6.pyc"

Good luck